# The yocto-layer script is missing from my install of poky

Tags: yocto

I am using the latest warrior release of poky and am on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine.  My poky/scripts folder is missing the yocto-layer script.  There is only a yocto-check-layer and yocto-check-layer-wrapper script.  How do I get the yocto-layer script?

Answer (score 6):

```
commit 31684e868588121a4fcc6a966a509e8281ec9f9d
Author: Joshua Lock <joshua.g.lock@intel.com>
Date:   Mon Oct 23 17:34:20 2017 +0100

    yocto-layer: remove this tool

    The bitake-layers tool in bitbake is much more featurful, widely used and
    better maintained.
```

Use `bitbake-layers` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot - took me a while to get an answer regarding `bitbake-layers` vs. `yocto-layer`. It puzzled me to find a lot references to `yocto-layer` but do not have the command in Poky Warrior.